# Get List of Terms based on a given term (different taxonomy)

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, terms

I have two taxonomy and a post type.

1. Post type: Employee (`employee`)
2. Taxonomy: Location (term example `chicago`, id 1)
3. Taxonomy: Job Title (`job-title`)

I want to list all job title based on a particular location. If CPT not available on that location the job title shouldn't be added.

I have tried to use WP_Term_Query() and wp_terms() but haven't found a way.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a two step process for that.

1. Get all the posts from the location (Using `WP_Query()`. You will only need the ID of the posts, so `get_posts()` will do too.),
2. Now use `wp_get_post_terms()` to retrieve the job titles from the posts.